# Is it possible to specify install location of pop!_shop apps?

Tags: pop-os, flatpak

The drive that the OS is installed on is very small. I would like to specify apps to be installed to another drive that I have mounted in a '/data' directory. Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know, Pop! Shop uses apt as the package manager and much of the installed programs will install to /usr/share. I don't see why you couldn't create a separate mount point for that on your data drive and copy the contents over other than this possibly messing with the boot process. I would wait for someone more experienced than I am to weigh in before trying this out.